# Evaluating $\cos^{-1}(\sin(-17))$

Tags: trigonometry

I had this question on my test I took today, and I'm confused if my answer's right.

I had to find the value of

$$\cos^{-1}(\sin(-17))$$

Okay, first, I drew a triangle. And, after, I let a and b for each line related to sin -17, so that we can say sin (-17) is b/a. And then, I realized cos ^(-1)(b/a) is the other angle than -17 and the right angle. I said the answer was 73, subtracting 17 from 90, since I thought -17 was an way of expressing that the triangle is in the third or fourth quadrant, and the actual angle is 17. However, I heard these kids saying that the answer's 107, since the angles should add up to 90, and 107+(-17) =90. I'm simultaneously confused and frustrated. What's the answer?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is hard to follow my process, right?  Sorry..  don't know how to draw triangles and a whole lot of other stuffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you meant ?
$$\cos^{-1}(\sin(-17))=\cos^{-1}(\cos(90-(-17)))=\cos^{-1}(\cos(90+17))= 90+17=107$$

Because you have for complementary angles that

$$\sin(\alpha)=\cos(\frac {\pi}2-\alpha)$$
Or in degree
$$\sin(\alpha)=\cos(90-\alpha)$$
but you have 
$$\alpha =-17$$
So it 's 107

Comment: yeah, but then the answer's 73 not 107?

Comment: @Isham You have got radians and degrees mixed up

Comment: then the answer's 73 not 107? oh thanks very much. I'm very relieved!!!

Comment: however, your answer's accepted :)  just wait a minute.

Comment: Yes @JohnDoe doe ...Thanks it's .correted

Comment: thanks for your effort isham!  really appreciated!

Comment: eight grade math is too hard~

Comment: @user547075 it's 107 ...

Comment: oh.... doesn't matter lol  thanks!

Comment: yw @user547075 .....